# How to install ABCpdf without Admin Privs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, abcpdf

I have a project in visual studio written in C# that uses ABCpdf to create a PDF page count. I set the install to be instanced as the project is deployed on a server and the project is run without admin rights as our IT department does not want to have a GMSA with admin privs to run it (it runs as a nightly windows task schedule). My issue is the application fails when it tries to generate the PDF due to access denied when installing the license. If I run the application as administrator on the server it runs fine, so it's definitely something to do with no admin rights when installing the license (or other aspects perhaps to run).

My code for installing looks like this:

```
try  {  string sResult; 
        if (WebSupergoo.ABCpdf11.XSettings.InstallRedistributionLicense("<license string>"))
                {
                    sResult = "License Installed Successfully: " + WebSupergoo.ABCpdf11.XSettings.LicenseDescription;
                }

                else
                {
                    sResult = "License Installation Failed";
                }
       <does other formatting things for the pdf creation after this in the try catch>
```

Does anyone know how to get this working without admin rights, or do you know the specific task or registry item it modifies so I can give the GMSA access just to that without full privs? Any help would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd say your IT department has the right of it, your application , to generate a PDF should not NEED administrative rights. If it's to install the license, could it be done during the installation/configuration process (which as a one time scenario could maybe be done witha administrative rights) ?

Comment: So instead of installing in code for each instance, you're saying install it directly on the server? If so how do I call the abcpdf to run in code? I wouldn't need the install piece anymore, but I assume there's syntax to open and use the abcpdf on the server its then running on. Sorry I'm very very new to all this!! I think they'd be fine if I installed it ahead of time on the server as a one time thing, but wasn't sure if that is 'proper' for an application since applications should be deployed with everything it needs rather then pre installing an outside app for it to work?

Comment: I've never used this particular library, It's however pretty common for the license to only need to be set once per machine and/or user account, I'd recommend to refer to abcpdf documentation.